# Cannot access a shared folder: "The server may not exist or it is unavailable at this time."

Tags: finder, network, imac, catalina, sharing

I’m trying to connect to a "server" by following [the ZDNet tutorial "How to connect macOS to a shared folder on your network"](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-connect-macos-to-a-shared-folder-on-your-network/), but I cannot spot the “server” on Finder->Network, even after [checking the checkboxes on Finder preferences as the official Apple tutorial suggests](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-your-mac-cant-connect-to-another-computer-mchlp1656/10.15/mac/10.15).

The [official Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/servers-shared-computers-connect-mac-mchlp3015/10.15/mac/10.15) says that I should be able to connect to “Mac computers that have file sharing turned on”, but I still cannot use Finder->Go->Connect to Server and connect to “smb://172.16.103.243” or “smb://iMac-de-lab2208-pc14.local”, nor the “afp://“ variants.

I keep getting:

> There was a problem connecting to the server “< server name >”.
>
> The server may not exist or it is unavailable at this time. Check the server name or IP address, check your network connection, and then try again.

I did set up the folder share by following [the official Apple tutorial](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-file-sharing-on-mac-mh17131/10.15/mac/10.15).

So, how can I find what is going wrong with just simply accessing a shared folder?

Both iMacs are running Catalina.

**What has been attempted so far?**

**1 - Can you reach the “server” you want to access?**

Yes:

- I get 100% replies when `ping 172.16.103.243`;
- when `ping iMac-de-lab2208-pc14.local` I get an error:

> ping: cannot resolve iMac-de-lab2208-pc14.local: unknown host

Which doesn't matters, since using the IP address is enough for me.

**2 - How about mounting the server through the Terminal?**

I was going to do:

1. `sudo mkdir /Volumes/File_Share`
2. `mount -t smbfs smb://user@<ipaddress> /Volumes/File_Share`
3. `ls /Volumes/File_Share`

But got an error on step 2:

```
mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Operation timed out
mount: /Volumes/File_Share failed with 68
```

**3 - Maybe disabling the firewall?**

After `sudo pfctl -d`, I still could not connect the client to the server by means of "File Sharing".

I could still ping them successfully.

**4 - How about using SSH instead of File Share?**

I followed [the official Apple tutorial on how to set up Remote Login](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/allow-a-remote-computer-to-access-your-mac-mchlp1066/10.15/mac/10.15) on 3 iMacs, but the Settings screen on these 3 iMacs never says it was enabled. Instead, they hang on a yellow sign that says:

> Starting Remote Login...

While they hang on "Starting...", `ssh < user >@< IP >` resulted at all times in the error:

> ssh: connect to host < IP > port 22: Connection refused

Using `pfctl -d` changed nothing.

I could still ping them successfully.

**5 - Isn't this a bug?**

[An Apple Community/Apple Discussions thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253932000) that I linked previously states that this hanging yellow sign on "Starting..." is a bug introduced by a 2022 security update for Mac OS Catalina.

[One reply there](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253932000?answerId=257625077022#257625077022) says to use `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`, but this just changes the error to:

> key_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

The yellow sign keeps there.

Comment: Can you reach the “server” you want to access?  Open terminal and type `ping <ipaddress>`. Do you get a response?

Comment: @Allan I get 100% replies when `ping 172.16.103.243`; when `ping iMac-de-lab2208-pc14.local` I get: "ping: cannot resolve iMac-de-lab2208-pc14.local: unknown host".

Comment: That just means it cannot resolve that name.  If I remember from your other question, you’re in an organization (government).  You shouldn’t be using the `.local` domain; it should be assigned by DHCP.  The on prem DNS servers aren’t going to know anything about `.local`.

Comment: What happens when you try to connect SMB using the IP address?

Comment: @Allan As said on the original question: "I still cannot use Finder->Go->'Connect to Server' and connect to 'smb://172.16.103.243'."

Comment: What is the error message?  Do you have file sharing enabled on the target?

Comment: @Allan As said on the original question, the error message is: "There was a problem connecting to the server '< server name >'. The server may not exist or it is unavailable at this time. Check the server name or IP address, check your network connection, and then try again.". And, also on the original question: "I did set up the folder share by following [the official Apple tutorial](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-file-sharing-on-mac-mh17131/10.15/mac/10.15)."

Comment: Do this in Terminal:  `sudo mkdir /Volumes/File_Share`.  You’ll be prompted for a password.  Enter yours.  Next, issue the command `mount -t smbfs smb://user@<ipaddress> /Volumes/File_Share`. You will be asked for **that** user’s password.  Enter that.  Can you connect?  If so, what does `ls /Volumes/File_Share` produce?

Comment: @Allan I can still ping the server, but the second command failed: error line 1 is "mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Operation timed out", error line 2 is "mount: /Volumes/File_Share failed with 68". It seems that there is something tricky on the official tutorial about how to share a folder. I'm not trusting that the folder is correctly shared.

Comment: It could be any  of three possibilities:  1) You have the wrong IP.  2) There’s a firewall on the target or 3) File sharing isn’t enabled.   Can you verify that the target machine has it’s firewall turned off?  (On the target) Issue the command `pfctl -d`.  That will turn off the built in pf firewall.  Do the same on the local machine.

Comment: @Allan The IP is not wrong, because I checked it on 'System Preferences'->Networking and it was, and still is, "172.16.103.243". It does not seems to exist a firewall on the server, as the command `pfctl -d` returned these 3 error lines: "No ALTQ support in kernel", "ALTQ related functions disabled", "pfctl: pf not enabled". So the hypothesis about something wrong with the file sharing seems more plausible.

Comment: That IP address, just to confirm…that’s to the *server*, correct?  As far as the firewall goes, that’s the normal message you get when disabling it regardless if enabled or not.  Are you using a user/pass with access to those shares?  Do you have remote login enabled?

Comment: @Allan "172.16.103.243" was the assigned IP address to the "server" by means of DHCP. Now that I turned it off, maybe it will get another IP when I turn it back on another day. Nothing unusual here. I'm not using a user/pass and I'm unaware of remote login. As originally said, "I did set up the folder share by following [the official Apple tutorial](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-file-sharing-on-mac-mh17131/10.15/mac/10.15)." Maybe it misses something? Or maybe isn't the best way to do it?

Comment: Remote login is different than the Shared Folder.  Can you enable it?  This way you don’t have to go back and forth between computers.

Comment: @Allan Very helpful advice. I indeed don't care which form the "share" takes, provided that I can copy files using the network.  I followed now [the official Apple tutorial on how to set up Remote Login](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/allow-a-remote-computer-to-access-your-mac-mchlp1066/10.15/mac/10.15) on 3 iMacs, but the server screen never says it was enabled. It instead [hangs on a yellow sign "Starting Remote Login..."](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253932000). Also, "Share Folders" became disabled on the 3 iMacs, and cannot be reenabled anymore by using the checkbox.

Comment: @Allan Oh, by the way, while the yellow sign was hanging on "Starting...", I could ping every iMac from any other of the 3 iMacs. But `ssh < user >@< IP >` resulted at all times in the error "ssh: connect to host < IP > port 22: Connection refused". Using `pfctl -d` changed nothing.

Comment: Are these Mac’s managed by MDM software (Apple Business Manager, JAMF, etc.) by chance?  Also, from Terminal, execute this command `sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on `. This will enable remote login without using the GUI.  Let me know what errors you get, if any.  If none, try connecting to that computer from another via ssh.

Comment: @Allan [The Apple Community/Apple Discussions thread that I linked previously](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253932000) states that this hanging yellow sign on "Starting..." is a bug introduced by a 2022 security update for Mac OS Catalina. [One reply there](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253932000?answerId=257625077022#257625077022) that says to use `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`, but this just changes the error to: "key_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer", and the yellow sign keeps there.

Comment: The “yellow sign” as you call it is just an indicator and not helpful in determining the actual problem.  It may be a disk permission issue which we can overcome.  Those indicators are about as useful as “check engine light” in your car.  We need good data to fix.

Comment: @Allan `sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on` returns "setremotelogin: Turning Remote Login on or off Requires Full Disk Access privileges". I'm already using an "Admin" account. I'm unaware of "MDM software (Apple Business Manager, JAMF, etc.)", and I don't know (yet) how to properly check if these are present or not.

Comment: Follow the instructions [here](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/troubleshooting/indexing/terminal-full-disk-access/) to enable Full Disk Access for Terminal, then try again.

Comment: @Allan I enabled, on all 3 iMacs, "Full Disk Access" for "Terminal" following [that "Alfred App" Tutorial you pointed out to me](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/troubleshooting/indexing/terminal-full-disk-access/). Now, running `sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on` results on a brand new error, being it the same on all 3 iMacs: "systemsetup[...:.....]###Error:-1 File:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Admin/Admin-820.6/InternetServices.m Line:359".

Comment: That’s more than a disk permissions thing.  That’s Apple code.  I am going to have to try and research that more.  I’d have you try installing an alternate sshd server, but that might be out of your wheelhouse.

Comment: @Allan Thank you for your dedication so far. 
For the case that LAN sharing cannot be enabled at all, I'm already thinking about alternatives for having these files available on multiple iMacs, as this turns out to be necessary already this week. 
But it would be, anyway, really insighful and interesting to discover why LAN sharing don't work in this particular case, and an answer that, eventually, shines light on this matter, will be accepted. (I'm trying to tell that the problem can just not be fixed, but a good explanation of why it is not possible will be a valid answer)

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Are all computers on the same local network (that is, do IP adresses of all affected Macs start with 172.16.103)? If that's not the case, the router may be blocking SMB/CIFS packets. If that's the case, check if the file server is reachable: running `nc -z 172.16.103.243 445` on a client (or on the file server, for that matter) should return `Connection to 172.16.103.243 port 445 [tcp/microsoft-ds] succeeded!`.